# Using queryParams instead of Json body in Restassured API testing

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

I am using RestAssured library to automate API responses in Java language and here is the API body I use:

```
{



"meta": {
    "language": "en",
    "marketCountry": "IN",
    "sourceUrl": "https://cj-gaq-dev.logistics.dhl/regular-shipment.html?en-AU"
},
"contactInformation": {
    "company": "test",
    "firstName": "test",
    "lastName": "test",
    "address": "test",
    "zip": "test",
    "city": "test",
    "country": "IN",
    "countryDisplay": "India",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "phoneNumber": "2324243243",
    "comments": "test"
},
"shipmentScale": {
    "domestic": false,
    "regional": false,
    "global": true
},
"shipmentProduct": {
    "FREIGHT": {
        "numberOfShipments": "50",
        "frequency": "WEEKLY",
        "checked": true
    }



}
```

instead of using the whole api body I wanna use queryParameters. 
Is there a way doing that?

This is what I have been using so far and keep getting 422 status code error:

```
String result = given().header("Content-Type","application/json" )
            .header("Accept","application/json").log().all().queryParam("marketCountry", "IN").queryParam("shipmentScale.domestic", "false")
            .queryParam("shipmentScale.regional", "false").queryParam("shipmentScale.global", "true")
            .queryParam("shipmentProduct.FREIGHT.checked", "true")
            .queryParam("shipmentProduct.FREIGHT.numberOfShipments", "50")
            .queryParam("shipmentProduct.FREIGHT.frequency", "WEEKLY")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.company", "test")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.firstName", "test")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.lastName", "test")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.address", "test")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.zip", "test")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.city", "test")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.email", "test@test.com")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.phoneNumber", "213456")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.comments", "test")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.country", "IN")
            .queryParam("contactInformation.comments", "test")
            .when().post().then().assertThat().statusCode(200).extract().response().asString();
```

Comment: That does not make sense from a REST perspective. You could use form parameters instead.

Comment: What is "form" parameters?

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all :) FormParam and QueryParam are part of the resource identifies, why do you want to pass it as a part of the URI and not pass it as a payload ?

Comment: Could you provide an example plz?

Comment: what do you mean by "provide an example" ? Just wrap the whole request into `.post()` and that's all

Comment: There is a .post( ) method at last line

Comment: what I meant was posts the complete payload in the `.post()` ex - `.post(json)`

Comment: @abbas - can you update the question with the API documentation of the API that you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to using RestAssured library to automate API responses in Java language. See the java class below:

```
public class Basics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://12.23.454.55";
        given().log().all().queryParam("key", "mykey123").header("Content-Type","application/json")
        .body("{\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\"meta\": {\r\n" + 
                "    \"language\": \"en\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"marketCountry\": \"IN\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"sourceUrl\": \"https://cj-gaq-dev.logistics.dhl/regular-shipment.html?en-AU\"\r\n" + 
                "},\r\n" + 
                "\"contactInformation\": {\r\n" + 
                "    \"company\": \"test\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"firstName\": \"test\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"lastName\": \"test\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"address\": \"test\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"zip\": \"test\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"city\": \"test\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"country\": \"IN\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"countryDisplay\": \"India\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"email\": \"test@test.com\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"phoneNumber\": \"2324243243\",\r\n" + 
                "    \"comments\": \"test\"\r\n" + 
                "},\r\n" + 
                "\"shipmentScale\": {\r\n" + 
                "    \"domestic\": false,\r\n" + 
                "    \"regional\": false,\r\n" + 
                "    \"global\": true\r\n" + 
                "},\r\n" + 
                "\"shipmentProduct\": {\r\n" + 
                "    \"FREIGHT\": {\r\n" + 
                "        \"numberOfShipments\": \"50\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"frequency\": \"WEEKLY\",\r\n" + 
                "        \"checked\": true\r\n" + 
                "    }\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "}").when().post("api/add/json")
        .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);

    }

}
```

If you like you can do more validation of the response or you can use the JsonPath class to parse your json responses in a bid to do further validation.

However, another approach is to keep your json request in a separate class' method and returning the object in your request body. Or better still you can explore the possibilities of a POJO java class.